# Comparison Report of migration from VSS 2005 to TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

We have Visual Source Safe 2005 and tried migrating on TFS 2010 in test environment but some of the nodes are missing and it looks like some data got skipped during migration and we have so many projects with multiple nodes and sub nodes so its hard to identify which nodes are missing. What I want to know is that is there any built-in tool available to give me a comparison report from source to target that what's missing in target compare to source.

Answer (score 0):

Could you download the source from the two trees and use a recursive folder diff tool?